# Series convergens change for the same series quation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I would appreciate if someone can help me think of a series that follows the following rules:

$$\lim_{n\to∞}(a_n)=∞, \lim_{n\to∞}({a_{n+1} \over a_n})=0$$

After a lot of thinking, i doubt that such a series even exists, but I am unsure on to how to prove it.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 0,$$
then there is $N\in \mathbb N$ so that 
$$\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| < \frac 12$$
for all $n \ge N$. Then by induction we have 
$$|a_n| < |a_N|$$
for all $n\ge N$. Thus 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \infty$$
is impossible.

Comment: It may be my fault that i haven't stated it, and sorry for the ignorance, but what happens to $a_n$ at -∞?

Comment: You mean something like $a_{-1}, a_{-2}, a_{-3}, \cdots$ and $\lim_{n\to -\infty} $ instead of $\lim_{n\to \infty}$? @YonatanIzutskiver

Comment: yes, for example the series $a_n$=$(-n)$, converges to -$\infty$

Comment: @YonatanIzutskiver It doesnt really matter if $a_n$ goes to $\infty$ or $-\infty$. My answer shows that if the second limit is zero, then $a_n$ has to be bounded.